# comparison unable to compare

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

Unable to get ll = -15 even when the Flex builder console show correct result. Which part could I go wrong?

```
//b-a = (3) && c-a = (6)
if((naArray[i+1]-naArray[i])<=3 && (naArray[i+2]-naArray[i])==6) {
ll=-15;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint?

Comment: Have you checked that they are actually integers? Maybe there is some floating-point rounding, or a stray string involved...

Comment: I found ==6 should have been >=6 instead which somehow has large than 6. Thank for your comments, it is quite complicate to write a music sheet application.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer as such, but wanted to put in the screenshot.

I ran this piece of code in as3term, and it worked ok (replaced the arrays with the variables you commented a, b and c). You should do the same with those arrays and step through in debug mode.

[image]